# Better approach for iteration of array having length more than 2000 in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, performance

An sorted array of 2000 usernames available and I want to call a function which retrieves the username of the user when ever the  user publish a post.

Can arrays be used with foreach to iterate over the values  or some other methods in javascript which is more effient .

Comment: Please give more details about your array, what kind of data there. What is your approach?

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking with the first part, but yes, there is an [Array `forEach` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: data can be of username of more than 2000 users

Comment: Is this sorted array?

Comment: You can use combinatoin of array and hash a.k.a objects.

Comment: This may be of interest to you : https://jsperf.com/for-vs-foreach/75

Comment: Yes its sorted array

Comment: Please don't explain your question in the comments. Create a [mcve] and then [edit] your post with all the necessaries of a good question

Comment: What do you mean by "monitor the post of the users every time its published"?

Comment: @technical hello, Please do some research and implement some kind of search algorithm, as long as you mentioned you have a sorted array you can use binary search. Also 2000 elements in the array you can accomplish with regular for loop

Comment: Based on what input do you want to find the user? Are there multiple inputs or is it only an id? If it's only one input you could use a `Map`.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use object and access with literal key .

See example intro code snippet :

```js
 

var BEST_ACCESS = {};

// fill our object 
for (var j=0;j<2000;j++){

var str = "id_" + j;
BEST_ACCESS[str] = j


}


// access like this

 console.log( BEST_ACCESS["id_1212"] )
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the fastest method in javascript is:

```
for(int i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++ {
   do something
}
```

The difference with usual array is that you get the length just once.